# Astro do not found global.css on build

Tags: css, astrojs

I created a blog with astro, and initially, the CSS worked correctly. When I enter a post, it loads with the correct CSS. However, when I access it through the direct URL or reload the page, the global.css file is not found (404). On the dev-run all work correctly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUAxi.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaYrf.png)

I try adding the css into other files or localy but I didn't work.